# My Settings Automatically get reset in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I Have Developed many project in vb.net 2010 and in all the project i have used my Settings and all worked properly. But now in my new project There are 20 Setting in my Settings.... and every time i start my software it Automatically get reset to original value..... all 20 of them...... I can't find any problem in coding part i also tryed testing by creating semple setting and one button which will change that setting value. but when i re start software it's bach to original value ......

Plz give your suggestions for the same......

Comment: The user.config file is hard to find back.  Something wrong with it.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor, you'll see your program reading and (maybe) writing the file.  Now you know where it is located, have a look-see at the file.  Make sure it is using the same file again later.  Make sure your program terminates normally so the file gets updated.

Comment: Thanks For Quick Reply I Will Try And provide the Result...

Comment: are you expecting the settings from Project A to be available in Project B? or saying that the new project wont save them?  Check that **Project Properties -> Application** Enable App Framework and Save Settings On exit are checked.

Comment: Are you running this from within Visual Studio? Because when VS rebuilds the solution, it copies the original settings and config files from the project to the bin folder where the compiled program runs, effectively replacing anything that was there before.

Comment: Are you using any extensions like DevExpress or CodeIt.Right?  I've heard that these can change settings like you mention

Comment: @ Suzy No i am not using any extensions......

Comment: @ Joel Coehoom i know that and i was runing it after making setup and instaling it.... ....

Comment: @ Plutonix no i am trying to get setting in same project..... as i have mentationed that i have developed many project using setting and all are working fine but this one is accing abnormaly......

Comment: I Solved The Problem by creating a file in my installed directory Suppose xyz.dll and then i saved all the basic setting in that and every time software starts it loods all the setting from that file into respactive my settings and when software exit it will save all the my setting back to that xyz.dll file....... and it solved my problem........ and thanks to all for trying.......... :-)